# Is sensors for Arduino work with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot, android-things

I want to experiment with some sensors with my Raspberry Pi 3. For that, I searched for sensors to buy online. During the search some websites says "buy sensors for Arduino" and some says "buy sensors for Raspberry Pi". So. if I buy sensors for Arduino, will they work with Raspberry Pi or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware.

Comment: "Do train wheels work on my VW Golf?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'it depends" being the answer.

The short answer is: yes probably it will work on both.

The longer answer is you'll be doing some work arounds. (and each is case dependent).

---

For example the [arduino has analog pins](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins), but AndroidThings boards do not - you would need to use a Analog to Digital converter ([like this](https://github.com/blundell/ads1015) *or any other ADC*).

---

Android Things [supports these protocols & interfaces](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/index.html)
- I2C
- SPI
- UART
- PWM
- I2S

If the peripheral uses one of these, then yes it will more than likely work an AndroidThings (a raspberry pi).

---

AT also supports GPIO. However if the sensor only uses GPIO, it is likely to require a fast communication speed (in the range of 10's of nano seconds), but Android Things GPIO is slow (the frequency is in the range of 300± nano seconds) - so you'll probably find *these sensors* are not supported on AT (a raspberry pi).

---

If after all that you buy a sensor and it won't work with Android Things - you can still use the sensor with an Arduino board and then control the Arduino Board with a Raspberry Pi as a master ([like this](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/arduino-as-an-i2c-slave)).

Comment: SPI is not a protocol, nor are UART or PWM. I2C is just basic. None has higher layer functions. Said that: please refrain from answering off-topic questions. With 50k reps, you should help moderating the site and close-vote them instead.

Comment: "is just basic" is not a definition. Your idea of protocol is clearly different to mine. If I said "protocol/interface" would it please you? -1 for an answer that will clearly help the person is pretty pathetic just to try and "follow the rules".  Closing a legitimate question doesn't help anyone. If anything it should be migrated and if it was migrated the answer would go with it. Therefore I am happy I helped this person by answering the question.

Comment: You want to read [ask] to see which questions to answer and which to close. Also you should not assume someone leaving a comment is the same person who downvoted! And the question is clearly not legitimate **here**.

Comment: "clearly" is not the case. The reason for the close is "general hardware" of which arduinos and rPis are not. OP is clearly a programmer and this person seems to have written a helpful answer.

Comment: What's wrong with you guys? If someone wants to help, then let him help. Do not hang with how to ask instead concentrate on the mottos of this website.